# C# MongoDB Driver 2.0 converting "strict mode" Json to "mongo shell mode" BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I have a "strict mode" Json string where dates are prefixed with '$date'

```
"DateCreated\":{\"$date\":1444835457460}
```

I now need the string in "mongo shell mode" where

```
"DateCreated" : ISODate("2015-10-14T15:10:57.460+0000")
```

To achieve the "strict mode" I have used

```
.ToJson((new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Strict })
```

To convert back to "mongo shell mode" I try

```
.ToJson((new JsonWriterSettings { OutputMode = JsonOutputMode.Shell})
```

No luck, string is not converted and '$date' are still present (I was expecting ISODate...)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but for people who still stumble upon this question via Google like I did you may find the following useful.

Using `BsonDocument.Parse` from the C# MongoDB.Driver package:

```
//var str: '{ "SomeDate": { "$date": "2010-10-10T10:10:00+00:00" } }'
BsonDocument.Parse(str); // Result: {{ "SomeDate": ISODate("2010-10-10T10:10:00Z) }}
```

This also works for unix timestamps, e.g.: `{ "$date":1286705400000 }`.